# Is pointer casting always reversible?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, compatibility

I'm not sure what happens when there are clusters in system such as big.LITTLE or multi-socket server builts. Could one thread in cpu-A(32 bit native size for int, little-endian) cast integer pointer to char pointer and then data is processed in cpu-B(64 bit native size for int, big-endian) and is re-cast back to integer.

```
char * c = (char *)floatPtr;  // in cpu-A with float=4 bytes
..
float * f = (float *) charPtr; // in cpu-B with float=8 bytes

// or cpu switched to compatibility mode between these and started working like a 16-bit cpu?
```

Maybe code will be compiled running on a soft ip core of a fpga which has multiple core types inside?

What about alignment restrictions? Can a CPU-A need 8-byte aligned floats while CPU-B can work with 4-byte aligned floats in same motherboard?

I'm connecting C# with a "C" space C++ dll for opencl computing, I can't have templates in "C" space so I decided to use `char` based array allocator and aligner(and initializer) class for all kinds of buffers from floats to longs and needed to be sure before continuing any further.

Maybe I just warn in documentation so people don't run my library on their servers if they built exotic systems?

Comment: It the CPUs aren't compatible, can you really have a multi-threaded program running on them? Just using pointers without casting would create problems if the pointer was created on CPU-A and used on CPU-B.

Comment: And it's not just pointers -- global variables shared by the threads won't be compatible.

Comment: Then multi-cpu or multi-cluster systems will always have compatible cpus.

Comment: You said in the question that one thread is 32-bit little-endian, the other is 64-bit big-endian. That's not compatible.

Comment: I don't know, if some cpus are adjustable in a way to work as big endian, is this possible?

Comment: I haven't done any work with multi-processor systems like this. But it seems unlikely that you can have a single program running in this mode. When CPU-A writes to a variable, CPU-B won't be able to read that variable, because it's in the wrong format.